Guacamole how to ignore RDP certificates
I have an Ubuntu server which runs guacamole 1.5.5. When connecting to a Windows 11 host, it fails due to the name I am connecting to (10.0.0.5) does not match the certificate name (Test-Client).
When adding an Ubuntu Client with xrdp I have no issues, everything works fine.
I added a Windows 11 host with this config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user-mapping>
<authorize
    username="admin"
    password="password"
    encoding="plain">
    <connection name="Windows-Test-Client">
        <protocol>rdp</protocol>
        <param name="hostname">10.0.0.5</param>
        <param name="port">3389</param>
        <param name="username">azureuser</param>
        <param name="password">password</param>
        <param name="ignore-cert">true></param>
        <param name="security">any</param>
    </connection>
</authorize>

guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    Certificate verification failure 'unable to get local issuer certificate (20)' at stack position 0
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    CN = TestClient
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    @           WARNING: CERTIFICATE NAME MISMATCH!           @
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    The hostname used for this connection (10.0.0.5:3389)
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    does not match the name given in the certificate:
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    Common Name (CN):
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:            TestClient
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    A valid certificate for the wrong name should NOT be trusted!
guacd[71796]: INFO:     Certificate validation failed
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    certificate not trusted, aborting.
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    transport_connect_tls:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_TLS_CONNECT_FAILED [0x00020008]
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    SVC "rdpdr" disconnected.
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    SVC "rdpsnd" disconnected.
guacd[71796]: INFO:     RDP server closed/refused connection: SSL/TLS connection failed (untrusted/self-signed certificate?)
guacd[71796]: INFO:     User "@deefc922-81e6-487f-961c-010268f46c5a" disconnected (0 users remain)
guacd[71796]: INFO:     Last user of connection "$3592ef80-9f8c-4c7c-97b9-21037ec709a5" disconnected
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    Requesting termination of client...
guacd[71796]: DEBUG:    Client terminated successfully.
guacd[71792]: INFO:     Connection "$3592ef80-9f8c-4c7c-97b9-21037ec709a5" removed.
guacd[71792]: DEBUG:    Unable to request termination of client process: No such process
guacd[71792]: DEBUG:    All child processes for connection "$3592ef80-9f8c-4c7c-97b9-21037ec709a5" have been terminated.
^X^Cguacd[71792]: DEBUG:        Accepting of further client connection(s) interrupted by signal.


which confuses me, because I set ignore-cert to true.
Furthermore I tested the RDP port like this:
telnet 10.0.0.5 3389

Trying 10.0.0.5...
Connected to 10.0.0.5.
Escape character is '^]'.

which tells me the port works.
My guacamol.properties looks like this:
guacd-hostname: localhost
guacd-port: 4822
lib-directory: /usr/local/lib
auth-provider: net.sourceforge.guacamole.net.auth.simple.SimpleAuthenticationProvider
rdp-ignore-cert: true

Any help is much appreciated.

The certificate check is done as part of the TLS handshake – which happens after connecting to the TCP port, so the telnet test really doesn't say much...

Is it a typo? I notice an incorrect greater than sign after true
<param name="ignore-cert">true></param>
                              ^


Omg you saved my year haha, it really was just a typo. Idk if I should close the question now or just leave it here?
